# Calling functions in a for loop in one line if a condition is met

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to call a function, ignoring its output, in one line if a condition is met. My expected syntax is this:

```
f(i) if condition else continue for i in range(rng)
```

I can do it within a list like this:

```
[f(i) if condition else None for i in range(rng)]
```

But here I create a list although I do not need one. I know that Python is not the most suitable language to fine-tune performance and that this has nearly no effect, but it bothers me. Moreover, I think it makes the code look like the function has an output, or that the output is used.

**So, is there a way to call a function if a condition is met and do nothing if not, in a for loop and in one line, without doing anything else like creating an unneeded list?**

Comment: Python is supposed to also be readable so, what should concern you more is writing intelligible code. The first expression doesn't make sense and there's no reason to have it on one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(rng): condition and f(i)
```

But it's better to do it the normal way:

```
for i in range(rng):
    if condition:
        f(i)
```

Comment: Please don't encourage bad habits just because someone asked.

Comment: It's still too prominent. This suggests that the one-liner is OK, but there's something even better.

Comment: @chepner I'd say in some contexts it *is* ok, for example if being a one-liner is the challenge or they're doing codegolf and it helps.

Comment: There's an entirely separate site for golfing questions, and such challenges don't really meet the criteria of *practical* problems.

Answer (score 1):

You use a regular `for` loop; there are no "one-line" loop statements in Python, ignoring the trivial, discouraged examples of putting a single-line body on the same line as the `for` keyword (`for x in y: do_something(x)`).

```
for i in range(rng):
    if not condition:
        continue
    f(i)
```

If you want fewer lines, you can filter the initial iterable. This way, `i` is never bound to the value that would cause the condition to be `False` in the first place.

```
for i in filter(lambda x: condition, range(rng)):
    f(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this article will help you a lot:
https://medium.com/better-programming/lambda-map-and-filter-in-python-4935f248593
if you have iterable object and you want to run a function only if condition is true you can run it with filter:

```
filter(function, iterable)
```

and inside the function to check you condition

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are suggesting here. Is `function` supposed to be the `bool`-returning function that checks the conditions, or the function which performs the final action? You also do not make it clear that, on its own, that statement is a no-op. No action will be performed unless the iterator returned by `filter` is actually consumed. Lastly, the article you cite is for **Python 2**. The semantics of these functions have changed in more modern versions of Python.